# How to display the sum of weighted edges of a graph in R (igraph package)?

Tags: r, igraph

Here's an example graph:

```
*Vertices 3
1 
2 
3
*Arcs
1 2 1
1 3 4
2 3 1
```

The sum of weighted edges is 6. Is there any command to display these results of my graphs in R (igraph)? I haven't found any yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the Pajek graph spec from your example is in an a file called, say, `graph.txt`, then:

```
library(igraph)

g <- read.graph("graph.txt", format="pajek")
sum(E(g)$weight)
## [1] 6
```

is probably what you're looking for.